# What does enable mean in Oracle DDL constraint?

Tags: oracle

My understanding is the different between

```
NOT NULL
```

and

```
NOT NULL ENABLE
```

is that the later will also be be applied to existing data in the table.  If then you are starting from scratch is there any point in doing

```
NOT NULL ENABLE
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

`not null` is a constraint. The `enable` that follows it is optional if you want that constraint to be active (which is the default). So

```
NOT NULL
NOT NULL ENABLE
NOT NULL ENABLE VALIDATE
```

all mean the same thing (`validate` is also the default, `novalidate` being the other option), so there really isn't an "advantage" in specifying it fully (except perhaps for documentary purposes).

If you wanted that `not null` constraint to be disabled, you could say:

```
NOT NULL DISABLE -- equivalent to NOT NULL DISABLE NOVALIDATE
```

or

```
NOT NULL DISABLE VALIDATE
```

See the [Specifying Constraint State](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52214) docs for the details and use cases on this topic.